# iOS: Open Settings app Programmatically as Youtube app does

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ios5, youtube, settings

As we know Apple disabled this feature in iOS 5.1 and later:
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];`
that allowed users launch for ex **Settings app** from any apps.
I'm wondering how **YouTube iPhone app** does it? Because it can still launch **Settings app** from it's application with iOS 5.1 and later.
Maybe there is no solution but, I just wondering about the **way**, YouTube app developer found :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The YouTube app developer is Apple. They're not subject to the same rules as the rest of us.

Updated since someone kindly downvoted this **four-year-old answer** and brought it to my attention: you can now do this by opening a URL made from the  `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` string constant.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get a response for this question but can bring an argument to the discussion.
The RunKeeper app is able to launch the iphone pref app on iOS 6.1. I don't know how it makes that but you can verify by disabling the iPhone GPS location service and then go to the RunKeeeper. Sometimes, the app is able to allow you launching the iPhone Pref app by a Settings button in an alert view.

I don't think the RunKeeper developers have specific privileges from Apple.